# Using Kotlin I want to programmatically change an icon in the bottom_nav_menu from an activity but am unable to see the menu item

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Android Studio (Kotlin). In my res/menu folder I have a file called bottom_nav_menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miPlayers"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
        android:title="Players" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miPigInfo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pig_svgrepo_com"
        android:title="Pigs" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/textinput_placeholder"
        android:title="Won" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miAbout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_white"
        android:title="About" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_target_score_500"
        android:title="Target" />
</menu>
```

I want to access and change the icon programmatically in the last item miSettings from my MainActivity.kt. I am using viewBinding but if it is easier then I could use viewById.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do like this 
replace this id (R.id.miSettings) with your item id you want to change

`bottom_nav_menu.menu.findItem(R.id.miSettings).setIcon(R.drawable.your_drawable_name);`